# Tortoise SVN - post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with no output

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, post-commit-hook

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.8.1, Build 24570 and trying to commit files to 
remote repository. But It doesn't work because I'm receiving the message

```
Completed:  At revision: 5641
Error:      post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with no output.
```

The result is that nothing is committed to remote repository

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. It  works, because **post-commit hook** fired *only* after finishing commit to the repository and due to this can't block commits - refresh you RepoBrower's window in order to see new revision
2. It's **server-side hook**, you have to ask about problem ("why failed?" and "why I can't see any readable message?") your repository-admin